# Problems with spanish encoding with python?

Tags: python, parsing, text, encoding, coding-style

I'm working with python and spanish language text and I'm having a lot of troubles with the codification. I would like to preserve all punctuation symbols. Is there any way to wrap all the text as an object with it´s correct encoding?, how can i solve this encoding issues?. I'm also working on OSX by the way i dont know is this is the problem.

I all ready tried with: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

With this function i concatenate a folder with lots of .txt files:

```
import os
import shutil


def concatFiles():
    path = '/Users/user/Desktop/OpinionsTAG_txt/'
    files = os.listdir(path)
    with open("/Users/user/Desktop/output_concatFile.txt", "wb") as fo:
        for f in files:
            with open(os.path.join(path, f), "rb") as fi:
                shutil.copyfileobj(fi, fo)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    concatFiles()
```

The problem is the output: `Adem√°s_de adem√°s_de` is not preserving the punctuation symbols. This would be a correct output: `Además además`. Is there any way to wrap output_concatFile.txt as an object that preserve all the spanish text with no encoding errors in order to apply them some methods?. How can i solve this issue?.

Comment: text files have no way of embedding encoding information, other than possibly adding in a UTF BOM.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`io.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) in place of the built-in `open`, and specify the encoding of the file.

You have to know what the encoding is.  The file can't tell you. Your editor can't tell you. The person who made the files has to tell you.

Comment: How can i know what encoding is?